# как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку закрывался блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

у меня есть меню которое при нажатии на гамбургер открывается на весь экран.В меню есть список.Я прикрепил якори к блокам что бы при нажатии на ссылку в меню страница съезжала к этому блоку.Но проблема в том что меню остается на всю страницу.Я нашел скрипт

```
$("#links").click(function(){
  $("#menu").addClass("remove-menu");
});
```

в `.remove-menu`  я прописал `display:none` и меню на весь экран  исчезает но если снова нажать на бургер то оно уже не открывается.Что делать?

Comment: нужно больше кода, так как не понятно каким образом меню вообще открывается, явно не инлайновой установкой `display: block;`

Comment: @ MedvedevDev  https://codepen.io/zeliboba/pen/ELwOpX  залил на кодпен

Comment: Замени `$("#menu").addClass("remove-menu");` на `$("#menu").removeClass("open");`

Comment: @MedvedevDev очень благодарен)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам следует поменять  `.addClass("remove-menu");` на `.removeClass("open");`

```
$("#links").click(function(){
  $("#menu").removeClass("open");
});
```

p.s. спасибо за ответ [MedvedevDev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/242887/medvedevdev)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu").toggleClass("remove-menu");
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь сей метод устарел и в будущих версиях JQuery более не работает, так что использовать его не рекоммендуется.

Comment: @Telion  а конкретно в какой версии jQuery не работает toggleClass ?

Comment: начиная с `jQuery 3.0.`, `toggleClass ` не работает - depricated